# Adopting a fraction Graph in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, fractions

with this MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{CountOfSections}
\newcommand{\fracgraph}[3][1]{%
    % #1 = optional height
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \setcounter{CountOfSections}{0}%
        \foreach \Size/\Options in {#3} {%
            \stepcounter{CountOfSections}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\YCoord}{#1*\arabic{CountOfSections}}%
            \draw  (0,-\YCoord) rectangle (#2,-\YCoord+#1);
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xincrement}{#2/\Size}%
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\Size} {%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xcoord}{\x*\Xincrement}%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\XcoordLabel}{(\x-0.5)*\Xincrement}%
                \draw [fill=\Options]  ($(\Xcoord-\Xincrement,-\YCoord)$)  rectangle ($(\Xcoord,-\YCoord+#1)$);
                \node at ($(\XcoordLabel,-\YCoord+0.5*#1)$) {$\frac{1}{\Size}$};
            }%
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% begin document
\begin{document}

\fracgraph{12}{7/pink,10/gray!50}

\end{document}
```

I can create something like this:[image]

I found this code online and it is very handy. But I wish to adopt it a little, so that I can draw - for example - 6/7 and 8/10. The other recangles I wish to be white. How can I do that?

Well, I actually came closer to the solution, with adopting a few lines. I changed
`\foreach \Size/\Options in {#3}` 
into
`\foreach \Number/\Size/\Options in {#3}` 
and I added
 `\draw [fill=\Options] (0,-\YCoord) rectangle (#2*\Number/\Size,-\YCoord+#1);`

My new MWE is

```
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{CountOfSections}
\newcommand{\fracgraph}[3][1]{%
    % #1 = optional height
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \setcounter{CountOfSections}{0}%
        \foreach \Number/\Size/\Options in {#3} {%
            \stepcounter{CountOfSections}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\YCoord}{#1*\arabic{CountOfSections}}%
            \draw  (0,-\YCoord) rectangle (#2,-\YCoord+#1);
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xincrement}{#2/\Size}%
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\Size} {%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xcoord}{\x*\Xincrement}%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\XcoordLabel}{(\x-0.5)*\Xincrement}%
                \draw [fill=\Options] (0,-\YCoord) rectangle (#2*\Number/\Size,-\YCoord+#1);
                \draw [fill=white]  ($(\Xcoord-\Xincrement,-\YCoord)$)  rectangle ($(\Xcoord,-\YCoord+#1)$);
                \node at ($(\XcoordLabel,-\YCoord+0.5*#1)$) {$\frac{1}{\Size}$};
                
            }%
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% begin document
\begin{document}

\fracgraph{12}{6/7/pink,8/10/gray!50}

\end{document}
```

and it produces:

[image]

I wanna see the fractions on the entire pictures. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to show 6/7 and 8/10 at the center of pink and gray box?

Comment: @Tom That would be nice, but I would prefer, if the vertical lines would stay and in every box 1/7 or 1/10 is printed. I wish to have the color in the background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following variation of the code can do what you want. I streamlined the code a bit. The command `\fracgraph` now takes as second argument a list of values that consist of thee parts separated by slashes (instead of only two as before). The second part marks the last segment that should be filled.

To switch between the different values passed to `fill`, I make use PGF's `ifthenelse` function.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{CountOfSections}
\newcommand{\fracgraph}[3][1]{%
    % #1 = optional height
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \Size/\Stop/\Options [count=\c] in {#3} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\YCoord}{#1*\c}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xincrement}{#2/\Size}
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\Size} {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xcoord}{\x*\Xincrement}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\XcoordLabel}{(\x-0.5)*\Xincrement}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\XCoordFill}{ifthenelse(\x > \Stop, "none", "\Options")}
                \draw[fill=\XCoordFill] 
                    ($(\Xcoord-\Xincrement,-\YCoord)$) rectangle ($(\Xcoord,-\YCoord+#1)$);
                \node at ($(\XcoordLabel,-\YCoord+0.5*#1)$) {$\frac{1}{\Size}$};
            }%
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% begin document
\begin{document}

\fracgraph{12}{7/3/pink,10/9/gray!50}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is just awesome :)

Comment: Qrrbrbirlbel's answer streamlines the code even more. Choose your favorite =)

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but with your answer it was easier for me to introduce a small white line between the 2 fractions ;)

Answer (score 7):

With the help of the TeX primitive `\ifnum` we can make this basically a oneliner.

The size of the diagram is controlled by the values to `x` and `y` where – ignoring the line width –

- `x = 12cm` specifies the width of the diagram to be 12cm and
- `y =  1cm` specifies the height of one row.

Instead of a LaTeX counter `CountOfSections` we can just use the inbuilt PGFFor option `count = \Row`.

The nodes are placed halfway between the corner of each rectangle.

A little more work is necessary if `\Style`, i.e. the third variable of your list entries isn't just a color but should also change other settings.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\fracgraph[2][]{%
  \tikz[x=12cm,y=1cm,#1]
    \foreach[count=\Row] \Number/\Size/\Style in {#2}
      \foreach \NUMBER in {0, ..., \pgfinteval{\Size-1}}%
 % or \foreach[count=\NUMBER from 0]\throwaway in {1, ..., \Size}
        \draw[fill=\ifnum\NUMBER<\Number\Style\else none\fi] (\NUMBER/\Size, -\Row)
          rectangle node {$\tfrac{1}{\Size}$} +(1/\Size,-1);%
}
\begin{document}
\fracgraph{6/7/pink, 8/10/gray!50}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is awesome :) and also so much shorter :)